# EF: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
var context = context.MyEntity
.include(e => e.something)
.Include(e => e.scoring
    .Select(sc=>sc.scoring_parameters
        //This is problem
        .Where(scp =>scp.scoring_id == sc.scoring_id)
        .Select(scp =>scp.cis_scoring_parameters.cis_scoring_parameters_tabs)))
.include(e => e.something_else)
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id  == _id);
```

The where clausule gives error "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type." I have seen posts with this error but they doesn't fit into this. I don't know how to write my lambda in proper way. Can someone help?

Comment: The where clause is redundant if `scoring_id` is the FK from `scoring_parameter` to `scoring` and you configured your mappings correctly. Just try it without the where part.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter data in include like this. `Include` is used to tell EntityFramework which data to load. If `scoring_parameters.scoring_id` and `scoring.scoring_id` are related to each other, then you can try something like:

```
var context = context.MyEntity
    .include(e => e.something)
    .Include(e => e.scoring
        .Select(sc=>sc.scoring_parameters.Select(scp => scp.cis_scoring_parameters.cis_scoring_parameters_tabs)))
    .include(e => e.something_else)
    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.id  == _id);
```

I suppose that `scp.cis_scoring_parameters.cis_scoring_parameters_tabs` is also a navigation property.